# Diferença entre dois códigos

Tags: python, loop, if

O código 1, caso a variável num seja 1 ou 2 por exemplo, quando o `conv()` é chamado novamente e eu escolher a opção 3 de sair em seguida, roda o `print` Espero ter sido útil (: mas o programa não fecha, só da próxima vez que eu escolher a opção 3.

No código 2 o problema não ocorre, tudo funciona corretamente, eu queria saber qual seria a diferença que faz isso ocorrer.

## Código 1

```
def conv():

print("\nEscolha umas das duas opcoes abaixo!\n[1] Metro para Centimetro\n[2] Centimetro para Metro\n[3] Sair")
num = input("")
if num == 1:
    met = input("\nDigite o metro\n")
    result = float(met)*100
    print("\nA resposta e >> " + str(result) + " centimetros\n\n")
    conv()
if num == 2:
    cen = input("\nDigite o centimetro\n")
    result = float(cen)/100
    print("\nA resposta e >> " + str(result) + " metros\n\n")   
    conv()
if num == 3: 
    print("\nEspero ter sido util (:\n\n")
    sair()
else:
    print("\nOpcao invalida\n\n")
    conv()

def sair():
    exit

conv()
```

## Código 2

```
def conv():

print("\nEscolha umas das duas opcoes abaixo!\n[1] Metro para Centimetro\n[2] Centimetro para Metro\n[3] Sair")
num = input("")
if num == 1:
    met = input("\nDigite o metro\n")
    result = float(met)*100
    print("\nA resposta e >> " + str(result) + " centimetros\n\n")
    conv()
else:   
    if num == 2:
        cen = input("\nDigite o centimetro\n")
        result = float(cen)/100
        print("\nA resposta e >> " + str(result) + " metros\n\n")   
        conv()
    else:
        if num == 3: 
            print("\nEspero ter sido util (:\n\n")
            sair()
        else:
            print("\nOpcao invalida\n\n")
            conv()

def sair():

exit

conv()
```

Comment: Esse código tem alguns problemas, só resolver isso não quer dizer que ele ficará certo. Funcionar é diferente de estar certo. Pra consertar teria que reescrever o código. Não sei nem se eu consigo explicar o motivo para precisaria ter um conhecimento que parece que ainda não ter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código tem muitos erros. O correto não é ficar criando esse monte de função, é criar um laço de repetição. E o `if` pode ser usado como um bloco só, prefira `elif` sempre que fizer sentido.

O código pode ser melhorado. Por exemplo a saída ser de acordo com uma condição do `while`, ou tratar o erro que seria gerado se digitar letras onde se espera números, mas não vou apresentar tantos conceitos novos. No momento tente aprender o `while` e o `elif`.

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Escolha umas das duas opcoes abaixo!\n[1] Metro para Centimetro\n[2] Centimetro para Metro\n[3] Sair\n"))
    if num == 1:
        met = input("\nDigite o metro\n")
        result = float(met) * 100
        print("\nA resposta e >> " + str(result) + " centimetros\n\n")
    elif num == 2:
        cen = input("\nDigite o centimetro\n")
        result = float(cen) / 100
        print("\nA resposta e >> " + str(result) + " metros\n\n")   
    elif num == 3: 
        print("\nEspero ter sido util (:\n\n")
        break
    else:
        print("\nOpcao invalida\n\n")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aOEabv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lvlpwpgs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/BreakLoop.py).

Comment: Legal, obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, a primeira opção gasta menos poder de processamento, pois o compilador passa direto pelas condições sem entrar em condicionais filhas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.
Bom, o código em si está falho e possui muitos erros de lógica, não é recomendado que sejam criadas funções se o código for pequeno, em geral, funções são usadas quando existem um determinado código que deve ser repetido em outras localidades, assim o mesmo fica mais legível e enxuto, facilitando modificações.

Neste caso, a função *conv()* nem a função que sai do programa *sair()*, contudo, em aplicações do gênero pode ser utilizado um laço de repetição que executará os comandos até a condição seja falsa, assim nos referimos ao laço *While*.

Segue abaixo um pequeno algoritmo para a resolução do problema.

1. Utilize um loop while igual a True.
2. Enquanto while for True, entre com a escolha do usuário para metros ou centímetros .
3. Verifique qual foi a escolha do usuário, se 1, então converta para Metros, se 2, então converta para centímetros, se 3, então sai do programa.