# Por que uma função está chamando ela mesma?

Tags: python, sintaxe, recursão

```
def clinic():
    print "Voce acabou de entrar na clinica!"
    print "Voce entra pela porta a esquerda (left) ou a direita (right)?"
    answer = raw_input("Digite left (esquerda) ou right (direita) e pressione 'Enter'.").lower()
    if answer == "left" or answer == "l":
        print "Esta e a sala de Abuso Verbal, seu monte de caca de papagaio!"
    elif answer == "right" or answer == "r":
        print "E claro que esta e a Sala das Discussoes. Eu ja disse isso!"
    else:
        print "Voce nao escolheu esquerda ou direita. Tente de novo."
        clinic()
clinic()
```

Qual a necessidade desses **dois** `clinic()` no final? Somente 1 deles aparentemente funcionaria o código.

*Não foi eu quem escrevi o código, foi de um curso que estou fazendo.*

[image: código]

Comment: Pode confirmar a indentação do código? Tentei corrigir, mas preciso que me confirme se fiz certo (sem a indentação correta, não temos como avaliar corretamente).

Comment: Se o codigo acima estiver indentado corretamente  o ultimo clinic() chama o método pela primeira vez.

Comment: Em tempo: use Python3 em vez de python 2.7 - aí você poderá contar sua história com acentos, sem precisar ficar preocupado com erros de sintaxe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A última linha é um código isolado e manda executar o `clinic()`, sem ele nada seria executado. Funções são executadas apenas quando são chamadas.

Já o anterior está dentro da função `clinic()`, ou seja, ela chama ela mesma. Isso chama-se [recursão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101), mas provavelmente foi acidental. Isto pode causar problemas como o [*stack overflow*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101). Prefira fazer um código com um laço de repetição, provavelmente um [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) para repetir quando necessário.

Note que esta chama recursiva só ocorrerá se as condições anteriores do `if` foram falsas.

Então essa chamada não é necessária se o código for feito como deve ser feito.

Eu ensinei uma pessoa a melhor isso em [Diferença entre dois códigos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189716/101).

Fuja desse curso que está ensinando errado :)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse curso é do codeacademy, parece tão bom.. irei ler seu outro tópico pra clarear aqui

Comment: Por isso que não gosto de recomendar curso, quase todos estão errados.

Comment: Só para constar, graças sua explicação entendi o que ele quis fazer no código, se caso cair na condição falsa ele reexecuta o código de novo, então nesse caso é necessário mesmo chamar a clinic(), estou certo?

Comment: Acredito que, por padrão, a profundidade de recursão no Python é de 1000. Neste caso seria difícil alcancar, mas com certeza não é bom já criar maus vícios.

Comment: Na forma feita, sim, mas esta forma é problemática e não deve ser usada, nunca, a não ser em caso onde recursão faça sentido. @AndersonCarlosWoss sem dúvida, mas eu não ensino ninguém a fazer o que não deve, porque eu acredito no certo, não no que funciona, o que funciona pode parar de funcionar, o certo só se torna errado por mudança de requisito, e se era certo mesmo a mudança não é traumática. De fato é de pequenininho que se torce o pepino :D